# Why does my xaml bring up errors when its the same as the example on the material design website?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design

When copying in the sample XAML code from the material design startup guide, even though i have installed both material design and ShowMeTheXAML.msbuild, my XAML brings up an errors all focused on the use of the window tag in line

```
<Window x:Class="オフィスエスケープ.MainWindow"
        TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
        Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
        TextElement.FontWeight="Medium"
        TextElement.FontSize="14"
        FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Resources/Roboto/#Roboto"
</Window>
```

The error list and and my project tree can be seen here https://pasteboard.co/I8HrVTW.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Window is missing its namespace declarations (xmlns:...). Create an empty new window and compare the code with your own. They may have been ommitted for readability on whereever you copied that code from.

This is what Visual Studio auto-generates in a new blank window:

```
<Window x:Class="Your.Namespace.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Your.Namespace"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
   <Grid>

   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked in combination with a namespace being invalid in the app.xaml cheers :)